# turn off pagemark and number in classicthesis list of *

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I'd like to (consistently) disable chapter- and pagemarks for the first page of each "List of *" in the frontmatter chapters of classicthesis. The current style is inconsistent if you have several small <1 page Lists and one of them is pushed over to a page on its own. In such a case it suddenly gets a header while the other pages don't have one.

Now i obviously tried quick-fixing things with commands such as `\thispagestyle{empty}`, `\manualmark`, `\markboth{}{}`, `\ohead{}`..., even `\renewcommand{\pagemark}{}`. To my surprise the `\thispagestyle{empty}` command doesn't seem to have any effect at all. With `\markboth{}{}` i can at least get rid of the chaptername in the header, however i never managed to also kill the pagenumber.

So, any idea how can i get rid of the 1st page heading of chapters in the following MWE (sorry verbose (thinned down classicthesis example), search for "PROBLEMHERE")?

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm} % fix some latex issues see: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/fixltx2e.pdf
\documentclass[ twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,%1headlines,% letterpaper a4paper
                footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,abstractoff, % <--- obsolete, remove (todo)
                BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,%11pt,a4paper,%
                ngerman,american,%
                ]{scrreprt}

\PassOptionsToPackage{utf8}{inputenc}
  \usepackage{inputenc}

\PassOptionsToPackage{
  drafting=true,    % print version information on the bottom of the pages
  tocaligned=false, % the left column of the toc will be aligned (no indentation)
  dottedtoc=false,  % page numbers in ToC flushed right
  parts=true,       % use part division
  eulerchapternumbers=true, % use AMS Euler for chapter font (otherwise Palatino)
  linedheaders=false,       % chaper headers will have line above and beneath
  floatperchapter=true,     % numbering per chapter for all floats (i.e., Figure 1.1)
  listings=true,    % load listings package and setup LoL
  subfig=true,      % setup for preloaded subfig package
  eulermath=false,  % use awesome Euler fonts for mathematical formulae (only with pdfLaTeX)
  beramono=true,    % toggle a nice monospaced font (w/ bold)
  minionpro=false   % setup for minion pro font; use minion pro small caps as well (only with pdfLaTeX)
}{classicthesis}



\newcounter{dummy} % necessary for correct hyperlinks (to index, bib, etc.)
\newlength{\abcd} % for ab..z string length calculation
\providecommand{\mLyX}{L\kern-.1667em\lower.25em\hbox{Y}\kern-.125emX\@}
\newcommand{\ie}{i.\,e.}
\newcommand{\Ie}{I.\,e.}
\newcommand{\eg}{e.\,g.}
\newcommand{\Eg}{E.\,g.}

\usepackage{babel}


\PassOptionsToPackage{T1}{fontenc} % T2A for cyrillics
  \usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp} % fix warning with missing font shapes
\usepackage{scrhack} % fix warnings when using KOMA with listings package
\usepackage{xspace} % to get the spacing after macros right
\usepackage{mparhack} % get marginpar right
%\usepackage{fixltx2e} % fixes some LaTeX stuff --> since 2015 in the LaTeX kernel (see below)
\usepackage[latest]{latexrelease} % emulate newer kernel version if older is detected

\PassOptionsToPackage{smaller}{acronym}
  \usepackage{acronym} % nice macros for handling all acronyms in the thesis
  \def\bflabel#1{{\acsfont{#1}\hfill}}
  \def\aclabelfont#1{\acsfont{#1}}

\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage{listings}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyperfootnotes=false,pdfpagelabels}{hyperref}
  \usepackage{hyperref}  % backref linktocpage pagebackref
  \usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{classicthesis}

\begin{document}
\frenchspacing
\raggedbottom
\selectlanguage{american} % american ngerman
%\renewcommand*{\bibname}{new name}
%\setbibpreamble{}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{plain}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\cleardoublepage


%*******************************************************
% Table of Contents
%*******************************************************
%\phantomsection
\refstepcounter{dummy}
\pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{tableofcontents}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} % <-- 2 includes up to subsections in the ToC
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % <-- 3 numbers up to subsubsections
\manualmark
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}
\tableofcontents
\automark[section]{chapter}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\enspace\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
%*******************************************************
% List of Figures and of the Tables
%*******************************************************
\clearpage

\begingroup
    \let\clearpage\relax
    \let\cleardoublepage\relax
    \let\cleardoublepage\relax
    %*******************************************************
    % List of Figures
    %*******************************************************
    %\phantomsection
    \refstepcounter{dummy}
    %\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
    \pdfbookmark[1]{\listfigurename}{lof}
    \listoffigures

    \vspace{8ex}

    %*******************************************************
    % List of Tables
    %*******************************************************
    %\phantomsection
    \refstepcounter{dummy}
    %\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
    \pdfbookmark[1]{\listtablename}{lot}
    \listoftables

    \vspace{8ex}
    %\newpage

    %*******************************************************
    % List of Listings
    %*******************************************************
    %\phantomsection
    \refstepcounter{dummy}
    %\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\lstlistlistingname}
    \pdfbookmark[1]{\lstlistlistingname}{lol}
    \lstlistoflistings

    \vspace{8ex}

    %*******************************************************
    % Acronyms
    %*******************************************************
    %\phantomsection
    \refstepcounter{dummy}
    \pdfbookmark[1]{Acronyms}{acronyms}
    \markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Acronyms}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Acronyms}}
    \chapter*{Acronyms}
    \begin{acronym}[UMLX]
        \acro{DRY}{Don't Repeat Yourself}
        \acro{API}{Application Programming Interface}
        \acro{UML}{Unified Modeling Language}
    \end{acronym}
    \lipsum[1]

    \vspace{8ex}

    %*******************************************************
    % More Lists / Glossaries
    %*******************************************************
    %\phantomsection
    \refstepcounter{dummy}
    \pdfbookmark[1]{More Lists}{more}
    % PROBLEMHERE: (and no, just removing the following line or emptying it doesn't work)
    \markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{More Lists}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{More Lists}}
    \chapter*{More Lists}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item some
        \item other
        \item list
    \end{itemize}



    %*******************************************************
    % More Lists / Glossaries
    %*******************************************************
    %\phantomsection
    %\refstepcounter{dummy}
    %\pdfbookmark[1]{Even More Lists}{evenmore}
    %\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Even More Lists}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Even More Lists}}
    %\chapter*{More Lists}
    %\begin{itemize}
    %    \item some
    %    \item other
    %    \item list
    %\end{itemize}
    %\lipsum[1-3]
    %Would be cool if these pages actually kept its header, (only the first shouldn't have one)
    %\lipsum

\endgroup



%********************************************************************
% Mainmatter
%*******************************************************
\cleardoublepage\pagenumbering{arabic}
%\setcounter{page}{90}
% use \cleardoublepage here to avoid problems with pdfbookmark
\cleardoublepage
\part{Some Kind of Manual}
\chapter{Test 1}
text

\appendix
%\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\alph{chapter}}
\cleardoublepage
\part{Appendix}

\end{document}
% ********************************************************************
```

In other words: i'd like to remove the header in the first of the following pictures, but not the second:

[image: inconsistent header]

[image]

Comment: Ah, KOMA and `classicthesis`, a fatal combination ;-)

Comment: @Jörn You have `\pagestyle{plain}` followed by `\pagestyle{scrheadings}`. Why don't you simple remove the latter command? Move it to where you want the headers to start appearing, say before the `\pagenumbering{arabic}`

Comment: ah, sorry... that looks weird indeed, but it's a result of condensing the classicthesis skeleton for the mwe. The latter command is actually desired for "follow-up" pages in a chapter (e.g. if the TOC gets longer than one page i'd actually like the reminder header, but i'd like to consistently not show it on the first page as it's redundant there)

Answer (score 4):

This is not related to KOMA or classicthesis: \thispagestyle sets a boolean directly. This means that is subject to the "asynchronous page builder problem": It can affect "the previous page". As an example see this example where is sets the pagestyle of the first page and not the second as one would expect:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}

\markboth{Hallo}{Hallo}
abc

\vspace{45\baselineskip}

abc

\section*{a section}    
a \thispagestyle{empty}

\end{document}
```

Comment: ok, that explains the problem (and is a way better minimalistic example), but how to solve it? (even with the new clues my google foo isn't successful :-/) I tried moving the `\thispagestyle{empty}` further down, but that wasn't successful either. Is there any way to "defer" the execution?

Comment: Moving the command further down should work, after another paragraph the output routine should have been called, but there is naturally the danger that you again don't affect always the current page but now in some case the *next page*. This is the reason why it is normally not a good idea, to connect page styles with \section begins -- with \chapter there is no problem. One can try to fiddle with the \mark commands, in some setups they are solutions. One can also add labels and test for them in the header, but this is not a fast solution.